# Cannot get fancybox thumbnails to work

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, fancybox-2

So I feel like I've tried everything but just been unable to get the fancybox thumbails to work. Here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
            prevEffect  : 'none',
            nextEffect  : 'none',
            helpers : {
                title   : {
                    type: 'outside'
                },
                thumbs  : {
                    width   : 200,
                    height  : 200,
                    position:'top'
                }
            }
     });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="Images/royalty.jpg" title="Simple Cake">
    <img src="Images/royalty.jpg" alt="" />
</a>

<a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="http://lorempixel.com/output/business-q-c-50-50-10.jpg">
    <img src="Images/royalty.jpg" alt="" />
```

i know it's something small but I've been through the documentattion but just don't get it... What am I missing here? I'm getting the basic pics to show, but no thumbnails. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: The thumbnails are added by adding the helpers for both css and js: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

Comment: Yes, I've done all of this, but not luck. They aren't showing.

Comment: Here is my CSS and JS....

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7" ></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancyboxy.js"></script>

Comment: the strange thing is that I'm able to get the basic funcionality to work, however I don't think the thumbnail is actually working because I'm not seeing the div "fanvybox-thumb" showing up at all when I inspect element. I've copied the files correctly and put them in my headers all identically. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check in Chrome developer tools? Does it give you an error? If so, correct it.

Comment: There are no errors in Chrome Developer tools. Seems everything is fine on that front. The headers see the all of the js,css files. The thumbnail div is just not showing up. Makes no sense.

Comment: Ok I figured it out! I mistakenly put this in the CSS

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script> 

I'm guessing that shouldn't be there and causes an issue.